# sweet-alert no hace nada

Tags: laravel-6

tengo Laravel 6 y he seguido los pasos de https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert
pero no hay manera.

Adjunto los códigos de mi controlador y app.php.

En mi controller tengo:

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\UserFormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use App\Http\Requests;
use UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlertServiceProvider;
use Alert;
use  SweetAlert ;

public function destroy($id)
{
    $roles = DB::table('rol')->where('id',$id)->delete();

    alert()->success('You have been logged out.', 'Good bye!');
    return redirect('/admin/roles');
}
```

**En app.php**

```
'providers' => [ UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlertServiceProvider::class,

 'aliases' => [ 'Alert' => UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlert::class,
```

Si uso

```
alert()->success('You have been logged out.', 'Good bye!');
```

me elimina el registro pero no me da error ni mensaje ninguno.

Si uso

```
SweetAlert::message('Robots are working!');
```

directamente me tira el siguiente error:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
>   Class 'SweetAlert' not found
>
> A class import is missing
>   You have a missing class import. Try importing this class: UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlert.

Nada, he repasado el manual de GitHub y no hay manera, estoy estancado en esto dentro del proyecto, espero vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Tienes   `@include('sweet::alert')` en el html ?

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384883/sweet-alert-error-classuxweb-sweetalert-sweetalertserviceprovider) Revisa la respuesta que dan en esta otra pregunta.

Comment: @include('sweet::alert') en la vista directamente tengo, si Francisco

Comment: A class import is missing
    You have a missing class import. Try importing this class: 
    UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlert.

Comment: Todo igual revisando las respuestas :(